# Alluvial Charts - Flow is not showing

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, ggplotly

I have a table similar to this one:

```
Organization    Timeframe   Code                    id
1   Agencia1    Fortnight 1 International Affairs   1
2   Agencia2    Fortnight 1 Environment             2
3   Agencia2    Fortnight 1 Health                  4
4   Agencia2    Fortnight 1 Public Policy           5
5   Agencia1    Fortnight 2 Politics                6
6   Agencia2    Fortnight 2 Disaster                7
7   Agencia1    Fortnight 2 Public Policy           8
8   Agencia1    Fortnight 2 Federal Government      9
9   Agencia1    Fortnight 2 Business                10
10  Agencia1    Fortnight 3 Federal Government      11
11  Agencia2    Fortnight 3 Dissemination - COVID19 12
12  Agencia1    Fortnight 3 Transparency - COVID19  13
13  Agencia2    Fortnight 3 Economy - COVID19       14
14  Agencia1    Fortnight 3 Prevention - COVID19    15
15  Agencia1    Fortnight 4 Economy                 16
16  Agencia1    Fortnight 4 Media                   17
17  Agencia1    Fortnight 4 Leisure                 18
18  Agencia1    Fortnight 4 Politics                19
19  Agencia1    Fortnight 4 Prevention - COVID19    20
20  Agencia1    Fortnight 5 Prevention - COVID19    21
```

I would like to build an alluvial chart that could highlight the different topics covered by each organization during the fortnight. I managed to create a chart like this one but the flow isn't work.

[image]

So far, what I have done was it:

```
alluvial_data <- as.data.frame(FC_Outlets %>%select(Organization, Timeframe, Code))
alluvial_data <- alluvial_data %>% mutate(id = row_number())

#Remove duplicates
alluvial_data <- alluvial_data %>% 
  distinct(Organization, Timeframe, Code, .keep_all = TRUE)


# Convert Timeframe to Factor - Categorical Variable
alluvial_data$Timeframe <-as.factor(alluvial_data$Timeframe)

# Convert Code to String
alluvial_data$Code <-as.character(alluvial_data$Code)

library(RColorBrewer)

# Define the number of colors you want
nb.cols <- 10
mycolors <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8, "Set2"))(nb.cols)


# Chart
ggplot(alluvial_data,
       aes(x = Timeframe, stratum = Code, alluvium = id,
           fill = Code, label = Code)) +
  #scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set2") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycolors) +
  geom_flow(stat = "alluvium", lode.guidance = "frontback",
            color = "darkgray") +
  geom_stratum() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  ggtitle("Organizations")
```

Could you help me to identify why the alluvial chart is not working properly?

Answer (score 1):

It is due to incorrect usage of `aes` in `ggplot`. The following code

```
c <- c(LETTERS[1:4], LETTERS[2:6], LETTERS[3:7], LETTERS[3:8])
t <- c(rep("Fortnight 1",4), rep("Fortnight 2",5), rep("Fortnight 3",5), rep("Fortnight 4",6))
s <- c(rep(c("Female","Male"),10))
ag <- c(2,3,4,6,11,13)
f <- rnorm(20,20,99)
df <- data.frame(Timeframe=t,Code=c,Sex=s,Freq=round(abs(f))) %>% mutate(Organization=ifelse((row_number() %in% ag), "Agencia2","Agencia1" ))

alluvial_data <- as.data.frame(df %>%select(Organization, Timeframe, Code, Freq, Sex))
alluvial_data <- alluvial_data %>% mutate(id = row_number())

#Remove duplicates
alluvial_data <- alluvial_data %>% 
  distinct(Organization, Timeframe, Code, Sex, .keep_all = TRUE)

#levels(alluvial_data$Timeframe)

# Convert Timeframe to Factor - Categorical Variable
alluvial_data$Timeframe <-as.factor(alluvial_data$Timeframe)

# Convert Code to String
alluvial_data$Code <-as.character(alluvial_data$Code)

library(RColorBrewer)

# Define the number of colors you want
nb.cols <- 10
mycolors <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8, "Set2"))(nb.cols)
mycolor2 <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(2, "Set2"))(nb.cols)

# Chart
ggplot(alluvial_data,
       aes(y = Freq, axis1 = Organization, axis2 = Timeframe, axis3 = Code,fill=Sex)) +
  #scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set2") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Organization","Timeframe","Code"), expand=c(0.05,0.05)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycolors) +
  geom_flow(stat = "alluvium", lode.guidance = "frontback" #, color="grey"
             ) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/4, fill = "cyan", color = "grey") +
  geom_label(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  ggtitle("Organizations") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes = list(color=mycolors[1:2])))+
  labs(fill=NULL)
```

gives this output:

[image: output]

Comment: Hi @YBS, thanks for answering me. But instead of having in the axis Organization, Timeframe and Code, I would like to have like in the first picture, the timeframes: Fortnight 1, Fortnight 2, Fortnight 3, Fortnight 4 and Fortinight 5 (or even more). And also, instead of male and female, my idea was to have the Organizations.  Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, please change the axis according to your needs using your data. My data is just dummy data. Please note that in this data structure, `Timeframe` can only be one axis. If your data is still alluvial form, then you can do it. You can check with `is_alluvia_form()`